# Разбиение строк на массивы (C#)

Tags: c#

Всем привет. У меня такая проблема: 
Есть текст (предположим в text.txt) и в нем текст примерно такого содержания:

```
Blablabla 9f3
KKK 33
Pos 1 44 23
TextV "Вертикальность не помешает!"
Up 15
```

и мне надо сделать так, чтобы в переменную записывалось второе значение, например в переменную position нужно записать 1 44 23 (из Pos).
я только что пытался написать свой жалкий пример, но... потратив около часа так ничего и не придумал(
я просто не знаю как сделать ..
щас ещё раз попробую..

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("name.txt");
        string str = "";
        string []strLine;
        int i;
        string NamePos = "Pos";
        int []position;

        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            int i;
            i++;
            str += streamReader.ReadLine();
            strLine[i] = str.Split(new char[i][]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }//считали все слова и записали в массив
        streamReader.Close();
if(strcmp(strLine[i][j], NamePos)) //сравниваем с нужной нам строкой
{i++}else{while(!strLine[i][j])
        {position[j] = strLine[i][j]; j++}} // копируем
```

как-то так, но на over9000% уверен, что в коде миллиарды ошибок!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем так сложно? C# — очень простой язык.

```
var splitChars = new[] { ' ' }; // разбивать будем по пробелу

var result =
    File.ReadLines("name.txt") // прочитали все строки
        .Select(s => s.Split(splitChars, 2)) // поделили каждую на 2 части
        .Select(parts => parts.Skip(1).SingleOrDefault()) // выбрали вторую часть
        .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)) // отсеяли пустые строки
        .ToList(); // и сохранили в список
```

---

Если вам надо по имени параметра получить значение, лучше делать так:

```
Dictionary<string, string> config;

// ...
public void ReadConfig(string filename)
{
    config = File.ReadLines(filename)
                 .Select(s => s.Split(splitChars, 2))
                 .Where(parts => parts.Any()) // убрали пустые строки
                 .ToDictionary(parts => parts.First(),
                               parts => parts.Skip(1).SingleOrDefault());
}
```

Для случая множественных значений, можно сделать так:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> config;

// ...
public void ReadConfig(string filename)
{
    config = File.ReadLines(filename)
                 .Select(s => s.Split(splitChars)) // убрали "2"!
                 .Where(parts => parts.Any())
                 .ToDictionary(parts => parts.First(),
                               parts => parts.Skip(1).ToList());
}
```

Comment: @Timofffee: Ну например:

    config["Blablabla"] == "9f3"

и т. д.

Comment: @Timofffee: Как хотите. Сейчас сделано так, что всё пакуется в одно значение. Можно сделать так, чтобы `config["Blablabla"]` был массивом значений. Сейчас допишу код.

Comment: @Timofffee: Может, и не туда. Покажите код. PS: лимит комментариев заканчивается, удаляйте верхние.

Comment: @Timofffee: "Ошибка. Данный документ доступен только его владельцу."